# MVC Model is null during post

Tags: asp.net-mvc, http-post

Hi guys im having problems when posting, my model appears to be null on http post which is weird, there is no problems during the get method, everything populates as it should be but during post model is null. please help.

View

```
  @model ComplianceCheck.Models.ViewModel.ArrivalModel

  @for (int itemindex = 0, id = itemindex + 1; itemindex < Model.questionnaires.Count; itemindex++)
    {

        <tr>
            <td>
                @id
            </td>
            <td> 
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => Model.questionnaires[itemindex].Description)
            </td>
            <td>
                YES
                @Html.RadioButtonFor(modelItem => Model.questionnaires[itemindex].Answer, true, new { id = "rbYes", @checked = "checked" }) 
                 NO
                @Html.RadioButtonFor(modelItem => Model.questionnaires[itemindex].Answer, false, new { id = "rbNo" })

            </td>
             <td>
                  @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => Model.questionnaires[itemindex].WigsID)
             </td>
            <td>  

                  @Html.TextBoxFor(modelItem => Model.questionnaires[itemindex].Remarks, new { @style = "width:250px;" })
            </td>
        </tr>
```

Model

```
 public class ArrivalModel
{

    public ArrivalSearchModel searchModel = new ArrivalSearchModel();
    public List<ArrivalDataModel> data = new List<ArrivalDataModel>();
    public ArrivalSingleDataModel singledata = new ArrivalSingleDataModel();
    public List<ArrivalQuestionnaires> questionnaires = new List<ArrivalQuestionnaires>();
}

  public class ArrivalQuestionnaires
{
    public int QuestionID { get; set; }

    public string WigsID { get; set; }

    public string Area { get; set; }

    public string Description { get; set; }

    public bool Answer { get; set; }

    public string Remarks { get; set; }

}
```

Controller: some codes deleted to lessen question length

//Get works fine..

```
 GET: /Questionnaires/ (Create)
      public ActionResult QuestionnairesList(string txtDate, string Flightno, string Checker)
        {
            ArrivalModel model = new ArrivalModel();

            List<ArrivalQuestionnaires> arrivalQuestionnaires = new List<ArrivalQuestionnaires>();

  foreach (Question questionnaires in ArrivalService.GetAllQuestionnaires("Arrival"))
                {
                    ArrivalQuestionnaires toAdd = new ArrivalQuestionnaires
                    {
                        QuestionID = questionnaires.QuestionID,
                        WigsID = questionnaires.Wig.WigsCode,
                        Area = questionnaires.Area,
                        Description = questionnaires.Description,
                    };
                    arrivalQuestionnaires.Add(toAdd);
                }

                model.questionnaires = arrivalQuestionnaires;
            }

            return View(model);
        }

}
```

Here is the problem, httppost fires but model is null

```
[HttpPost]
        public ActionResult QuestionnairesList(ArrivalModel model)
        {}
```

Comment: Do you have `<form>` tag on your page? Could you check using any browser developer tools what is a content of the POST request that is sent back to the controller?

Comment: Do any of the other properties of `ArrivalModel` (`ArrivalSearchModel`, `ArrivalDataModel`, `ArrivalSingleDataModel`) have a property named `model`?

Comment: You have no getters/setters on your properties - have you omitted some code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your model has no getters/setters

```
public class ArrivalModel
{
  // Add constructor if you want to initialize properties
  public ArrivalModel()
  {
    searchModel = new ArrivalSearchModel();
    data = new List<ArrivalDataModel>();
    singledata = new ArrivalSingleDataModel();
    questionnaires = new List<ArrivalQuestionnaires>();
  }
  public ArrivalSearchModel searchModel { get; set; }
  public List<ArrivalDataModel> { get; set; }
  public ArrivalSingleDataModel singledata { get; set; }
  public List<ArrivalQuestionnaires> questionnaires { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your model is full of collections, try to read this article for the binding of the model

http://haacked.com/archive/2008/10/23/model-binding-to-a-list.aspx/

Comment: Why is that a problem?

Comment: Probably the defaultmodelbinder of MVC in that case is not able to recreate the collections of object.

Answer (score 0):

For this, `create editorTemplate for ArrivalQuestionnaires` and then bind to data in `ArrivalModel`.

[More information about editor Template](http://coding-in.net/asp-net-mvc-3-how-to-use-editortemplates/)